# JAVA_HOME is not working for Maven

Tags: java, windows, maven, java-home

I have tried setting up my `JAVA_HOME` with the path I have got from using the command where Java. But still when I am trying to launch `mvn.bat` it's not working. I have tried setting up `JAVA_HOME` with all the below paths:

1. `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25`
2. `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin`
3. `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe`

But none seems to work when using `mvn.bat`. Anyone any help please? I am using Windows 7 x86.

Comment: Can you try with `C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_25`?

Comment: Try making it a user variable instead of a system variable.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks every one. After I have set up the Path and M2 variable in my system variables it's now working. Previously I although I had JAVA_HOME and M2_HOME set up on my system, I did not have Path pointing to same location as does JAVA_HOME. Neither I had M2_PATH enabled.
 Now all fine. Thanks everyone